# Is a new String() of a constant byte array evaluated at compile time?

Tags: java

I have a constant byte array, for instance

```
static final byte[] myArray = "something".getBytes();
```

used to write somewhere (XML, JMS...), and I want to use the value "something" as a String without declaring a new constant (I know I should).

I was wondering, if I write

```
anObject.setMessage(new String(myArray));
```

is the expression `new String(myArray)` evaluated at compile time ?

[The java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) states that only String literals are evaluated at compile time, this is not a String literal but I don't see why it wouldn't be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "constant (byte) array". Array elements remain mutable, even if the reference to the array is final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the expression new String(myArray) evaluated at compile time ?

No. It's evaluated at runtime.

You can have it evaluated at compile time if you use:

```
static final String myString = "something";
```

and

```
anObject.setMessage(myString);
```

> I don't see why it wouldn't be evaluated at compile time.

This is described in [JLS Sec 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> Every time the [class instance creation] expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

But aside from that, it's not a constant expression if you use a `byte[]` as a parameter: even though you can't assign a new value to the `static final` array reference, you can still change the array elements. This should be of concern particularly as the `myArray` field is (or at least appears) non-private.

Additionally, `new String(byte[])` makes use of the JVM's default character encoding, which could be changed between evaluations of the expression.

Because `String` is immutable, a `static final String` *is* a constant. However, this doesn't mean that it could be evaluated at compile time if you use a string, because of the JLS quote above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Taking the question the other way around, for `myString.getBytes()`, would the entire expression be evaluated at compile time, or just the string literal and the getBytes call would be done at run time ?

Comment: @Cithel getBytes cannot be evaluated at compile time as the result might differ from run to run depending on the plateform defualt charset encoding

Answer (score 2):

> Is the expression `new String(myArray)` evaluated at compile time ?

No, using `new String` *will **always*** create a new `String` reference at runtime.